# Como fazer um Dowload no IE via VBA?

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel-vba

Olá estou utilizando o seguinte código para iniciar um dowload no Intenet Explorer.

```html
Public Sub Dashboard()
    Dim Navegador As InternetExplorer
    Dim objShellWindows As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
    Dim currentWindow As HTMLWindowProxy
    Dim url As String
    
    On Error GoTo Erro
    url = "http://..................../"
    Set Navegador = New InternetExplorer
    Navegador.navigate url
    Navegador.Visible = True

    Do While Navegador.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    'Faz login
    Navegador.document.getElementById("usuario").Value = "xxxxxxxx"
    Navegador.document.getElementById("senha").Value = "xxxxxx"
    Navegador.document.getElementById("bt_entrar").Click
'    Set Navegador = Nothing
'    Set Navegador = New InternetExplorer
'    Navegador.navigate url
'    Navegador.Visible = True
    
    Do While Navegador.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    Navegador.document.getElementById("submenu2_SatisfacaoGeral").Click
    Set currentWindow = Navegador.document.parentWindow
    currentWindow.execScript code:="chart.exportChart()"

Erro:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Next
 End Sub
```

acontece que eu não sei como eu posso "salvar como o download" definindo a pasta e o Nome do arquivo.

Comment: Já tentou usar [este método](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29367304/7690982)?

Comment: Esse não serve para o meu caso, o script que eu executo, já inicia o Download, eu preciso manipular a janela do IE, alterando nome do arquivo e local de salvamento.
De medida paliativa estou usando o .SendKeys:
`Set JanelaSite = IE.document.parentWindow
    JanelaSite.execScript code:="chart.exportChart()"
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    JanelaSite.Focus
    'JanelaSite.document.execCommandShowHelp ("SaveAs")
    tela.SendKeys "{TAB}"
    tela.SendKeys "{TAB}"
    tela.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
    tela.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
    tela.SendKeys "{ENTER}"`

Comment: Não entendo de IE, mas se for útil, encontrei alguns links: [1](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/567033-automate-file-download-dialog-box-without-sendkeys.html), [2](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/02/02/vbavb-netvb6click-opensavecancel-button-on-ie-download-window-part-ii/),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664260/click-on-an-ie-window-without-sendkeys-or-mouseevent-vba)

Answer (score 0):

Você consegue interagir com o PDF, por exemplo, baixando-o pelo URL criado para uma pasta especificada, usando a função URLDownloadToFile,

```
Declare Function URLDownloadToFile _
    Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" _
    (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
    Function DownloadFile(URL As String, LocalFilename As String) As Boolean
        Dim lngRetVal As Long
        lngRetVal = URLDownloadToFile(0, URL, LocalFilename, 0, 0)
        If lngRetVal = 0 Then DownloadFile = True
    End Function
    Sub test()
        URL = Navegador.LocationURL 'URL do pdf
        DownloadFile URL, "C:\PASTA\EXEMPLO.pdf" 'Pasta e nome do arquivo
    End Sub
```

Comment: Olá Marcelo, vou testar aqui e te falo.
Eu até consegui sem utilizar ".SendKeys", mas não consegui alterar o nome do arquivo e ainda esbarrei em outro problema, o IE começou a inserir Números (aleatórios) no nome do arquivo (acho que pelo número de download). Por isso tive que criar uma página em PHP e consegui fazer tudo que queria.

Comment: Tentei aqui, o problema é que no meu caso o comando que eu executo já inicia o download. Eu queria manipular a janela de Download pra alterar o nome do arquivo e o local.