# Ajuda com VBA e web para preencher campos de formulários web com dados de células e acionar botão de emissão de relatórios

Tags: java, html, jquery

Tenho o código abaixo que acessa o site, loga no mesmo, entra no menu gerencial. Na tela do menu gerencial eu tenho campos de formulários onde insiro dada inicial, data final, turno e o botão de gerar os relatórios. Achei que usando o HTMLDoc.all e os id dos formulários e do botão conseguiria preencher os dados conforme o valor imputado na planilha1 células c9 para data inicial, célula c11 para data final e célula 13 para turno. Porém não carrega os dados e nem clica no botão! Se alguém puder me ajudar ficarei eternamente grato! Desde já obrigado a todos! 
Segue o código abaixo:

Código VBA

```
Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
 
'Declara função Sleep
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems
#Else
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems
#End If
 
 
Sub Login()
 
Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim sURL As String
Dim elemCollection As Object
Dim obj As Object
Dim showhide As Object
Dim IE As Object
Planilha1.Select
 
 
'ACESSAR SITE IRCS----------------------------------
On Error GoTo Err_Clear
   sURL = "http://tdbsorsvr034/tdb-rcs-report/"
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
   oBrowser.Silent = True
   oBrowser.timeout = 60
   oBrowser.navigate sURL
   oBrowser.Visible = True
   
Do
Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
 
'INSERIR USUARIO E SENHA IRCS-----------------------
Set HTMLdoc = oBrowser.document
  HTMLdoc.all.j_username.Value = "bximenes"
  HTMLdoc.all.j_password.Value = "Bx123"
  HTMLdoc.all.loginBtnId.onclick
 
  
'PROCURA ELEMENTO GERENCIAL PARA AVANÇAR MENU-------
      EsperaIE IE, 2000
      Set link = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
    For Each l In link
        If l.innerText = "Gerencial" Then
            EsperaIE IE, 2000
            l.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next l
    
'INSERIR DATA INICIAL E DATA FINAL E CLICA EM RELATORIOS------

‘Tentei fazer da forma abaixo e não foi
      EsperaIE IE, 2000
      Set form = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("FormSearch")
    For Each f In form
        If f.innerText = "dateUntilId_input" Then
            EsperaIE IE, 2000
            f.Value = "20/02/2020 23:59:59"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next f
 
 
 ‘E da forma abaixo também não foi 
 
'  EsperaIE IE, 2000
'Set HTMLdoc = oBrowser.document
'  HTMLdoc.all.formSearch: dateFromId_inputdateFromId_input.Value = "Planilha1!C9"
'  HTMLdoc.all.formSearch: dateUntilId_input.Value = "Planilha1!C11"
'  HTMLdoc.all.formSearch: shiftId_label.Value = "Planilha1!C13"
'  HTMLdoc.all.formSearch: reportsId.onclick
 
 
For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If oHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then oHTML_Element.Click:
    Exit For
   
 
Next
Err_Clear:
Resume Next
 
 
 
End Sub`
```

Código página

```
pagina
 
 
`data inicial
<input id="formSearch:dateFromId_input" name="formSearch:dateFromId_input" type="text" value="26/02/2020 00:00:00" class="ui-inputfield ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all hasDatepicker" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-multiline="false">
‘data final
<input id="formSearch:dateUntilId_input" name="formSearch:dateUntilId_input" type="text" value="26/02/2020 23:59:59" class="ui-inputfield ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all hasDatepicker" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-multiline="false">
‘turno
<label id="formSearch:shiftId_label" class="ui-selectonemenu-label ui-inputfield ui-corner-all" style="width: 158px;">1</label>
‘botao relatorio
<button id="formSearch:reportsId" name="formSearch:reportsId" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only bt_search_100" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'formSearch:reportsId',update:'showDialogMsg'});return false;" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Relatórios</span></button>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caro Bruno, acho que essa vai ser tranquila.

Novamente, assim como na sua dúvida anterior, o método `getElementsByTagName` retorna uma coleção de elementos que tenham a Tag passada como parâmetro. No caso, pelos seus recortes do HTML da página, a tag que você procura alterar não é `FormSearch`, e sim `input` (para os campos de data inicial e final) e `button` (para o botão de relatórios). `FormSearch` é só um prefixo do nome, prática usada pelo designer web para organizar melhor os elementos da página.

Assim, para fazer o código dessa forma, a instrução correta seria `HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("input")` e `HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("button")`, aí dentro do `For` você testa se o objeto referenciado por `f` é o que você quer.

Mas essa não é a solução mais simples. Como os três elementos (data inicial, data final e botão) têm um `id` definido na página, e considerando que o atributo `id` é único (ou deveria, se a página estiver bem feita), o mais fácil é utilizar o método `getElementById`, que traz um único objeto, individual. Segue exemplo abaixo (inserir as declarações de variáveis no começo e inserir o código abaixo no seu código do comentário "INSERIR DATA INICIAL, ETC" em diante):

```
    Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim btRelatorioPorreta As HTMLButtonElement
    Dim strDataInicial As String, strDataFinal As String

    Do
        Set btRelatorioPorreta = HTMLDoc.getElementById("formSearch:reportsId")
        ' É recomendável inserir um timer aqui, pois se a página não carregar o botão, vai ficar num loop infinito. Se quiser, é só pedir que eu tenho esse código em algum lugar.
    Loop Until Not btRelatorioPorreta Is Nothing

    ' INSERIR DATA INICIAL E DATA FINAL E CLICAR EM RELATORIOS
    strDataInicial = "20/02/2020 23:59:59"
    strDataFinal = "21/02/2020 23:59:59"

    Do
        HTMLDoc.getElementById("formSearch:dateFromId_input").Value = strDataInicial
    Loop Until HTMLDoc.getElementById("formSearch:dateFromId_input").Value = strDataInicial

    Do
        HTMLDoc.getElementById("formSearch:dateUntilId_input").Value = strDataFinal
    Loop Until HTMLDoc.getElementById("formSearch:dateUntilId_input").Value = strDataFinal

    HTMLDoc.getElementById("formSearch:reportsId").Click
```

Além disso, vou explicar uma coisa que pode causar dúvida: eu coloquei as instruções de preencher as datas inicial e final dentro de um loop. Por quê? Porque na prática percebi que, às vezes, o VBA roda muito mais rápido do que o Internet Explorar processa, e a gente termina tendo alguns erros, porque faltou uma parte da data, ou algo assim.

Já tive muitos erros desse tipo, e por isso sempre faço esses loops, que garantem que o código só avançará se o conteúdo dos campos for adequadamente preenchido. Se você quiser, pode testar sem os `Do...Loops` e, caso passe a obter erros, você insere os loops.

Comment: Show de bola Cesar vc eh fera! Amanhã testarei o código que me passou! Certeza q vai dar certo! Um dia ainda fico bom no VBA igual a você! =) forte abraço!

Comment: Obrigado pelos elogios! Eu não sou tão bom assim não, mas ano passado comecei a fazer uma coisa pela minha empresa que parece ser similar ao que você está fazendo na sua, aí já passei por esses mesmos sofrimentos.

Comment: Uma das coisas que mais quebrou minha cabeça e que pode te acontecer, já que você está trabalhando com intranet: tinha vezes que, do nada, o objeto do Internet Explorer (no seu código é o oBrowser) dava um erro de "objeto desconectado dos clientes", algo assim. Se acontecer, pode perguntar aqui, é fácil de resolver. É um erro que costuma dar em intranet, por causa dos redirecionamentos.

Comment: Show de bola Cesar! Pode deixar que se ocorrer eu recorro ao fórum e a você kkkk! Tenho muitas ideias para facilitar a coleta de dados dos meus relatórios, estava pensando em algo que puxasse diretamente do banco de dados, só não sei se é possível! Mas é um projeto futuro pois tenho um painel em power BI que preciso abastece-ló com informações do mesmo sistema intranet. Muito obrigado por tudo!

Comment: Obrigado César, mais uma vez deu certo o código que você fez! estou indo passo por passo para conseguir gerar os relatórios. Logo mais caso não consiga desenvolver os passos seguintes tornarei a solicitar sua ajuda e a de todos do stackoverflow. Abraço.

Comment: Fico feliz por ajudar!

Comment: César uma dúvida, é possível passar os parâmetros para salvar determinado arquivo? Tipo local, nome, uma vez que ao clicar no botão relatório ele abre a caixa para informar onde desejo salvar o pdf. E também, se ao invés de gerar um pdf ele me gerasse um arquivo xls? Obrigado por tudo brother!

Comment: Eu já fiz isso usando o Chrome, através de uma interface chamada Selenium (que felizmente é gratuita). Na época, eu não consegui fazer pelo Internet Explorer, e depois eu não precisei mais fazer. Na pasta downloads não te serve?

Comment: Se você configurar manualmente o Explorer para salvar para determinada pasta em vez de perguntar, não te serve?

Comment: acho que não daria pelo fato de eu ter que renomear os arquivos. ao todo terei que baixar 4 arquivos em pdf e 1 em xls que o sistema me retorna. a não ser que no código eu consiga programar os nomes tipo assim: QC Daily report 1º "26 - 02 - 2020" onde a data em parenteses seja colocada automaticamente porem do dia anterior ao dia atual do sistema. Como se fosse usar a formula =hoje()-1. Dai até poderia ser salvo na pasta download

Comment: Achei este post : https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/244037/como-fazer-um-dowload-no-ie-via-vba. Sera que consigo alterar onde usa URL para chamar pelo botão e nao por URL?

Comment: Cesar, bom dia! Realizando os teste com o codigo que voce me passou esta rodando perfeito, porem encontrei um problema na questão de se o campo do excel estiver vazio, ele deveria limpar o campo do formulario web tambem, porem não esta limpando. Vou explicar: no excel eu coloquei celulas para dar entrada nos dados, dtinicial, dtfinal e turno. No codigo ele pega o valor destas celulas e copia para o campo do formulario web. porem para o campo turno as vezes preciso deixar vazio para pegar os 2 turnos. so que nao limpa.

Comment: tentei fazer desta forma mas não retornou o valor vazio: '    Do
        If strTurno = "" Then
        HTMLdoc.getElementById("formSearch:shiftId_label").Value = ""
        Else
        HTMLdoc.getElementById("formSearch:shiftId_label").Value = strTurno
        End If
        
            
    Loop Until HTMLdoc.getElementById("formSearch:shiftId_label").Value = strTurno'

Comment: Duas questões: 1) Qual foi o erro que deu?

Comment: Nenhum! Apenas não troca o valor! O campo turno tem uma lista onde seleciona 1, 2, 3 turno ou deixar ele em branco! Talvez por isso que qnd deixo a célula em branco ele não troca o valor do campo na página. Já se eu deixar preenchido com 1 ou 2 ele muda normalmente

Comment: 2) Como é o campo turno? Em tese, a label é só uma etiqueta para outro controle, portanto seu conteúdo não devia ser alterado pelo usuário. Deveria haver uma tag ```for``` no campo ```label```, ou ao menos um outro controle dentro da tag ```label```. O que é, visualmente, esse label? Você pode mandar o código ao redor dele?

Comment: Agora só consigo mandar na segunda feira! Eu vi que tem outras informações, vi tbm que tem um selected estando para sempre iniciar com o 1 turno preenchido

Comment: Deve ter a ver com essas outras tags. Traz os outros elementos na segunda feira!

Comment: blz! Eu até tentei usar o outro nome que o elemento tem, fiz usando getElementById e tbm classname mas não adiantou. Não gera erro mas não preenche com vazio. Tanto eu mandando buscar o valor da célula no Excel quanto eu deixando = “” na linha de comando

Comment: Bom dia César, conforme lhe falei anteriormente, o codigo para a label turno tem um id input conforme codigo a seguir: <select name="formSearch:shiftId_input" id="formSearch:shiftId_input"><option value=""></option><option selected="selected" value="4050">1</option><option value="4051">2</option><option value="13100">3</option></select>. Já tentei trocar a id="formSearch:shiftId_label por input, ou somente deixei shiftID e mesmo assim ele ainda fica como 1 se eu deixar o campo vazio.